# TypeScript: How would I write the typings for a callable/extensible entity?

Tags: typescript

I have a javascript function/class that is both callable and extensible. Let's say it's named `Hello`.

`Hello` can be used in one of two ways:

`class Hi extends Hello { }`

or

`Hello('there');`

How would I write the typings for `Hello` so that TypeScript knows it's both callable and extensible?

Comment: When you call Hello("there") then Hello is a function. When you say extends Hello it is a class.  I think that you need Hello to be a class with a static method like "Say" so you can do this Hello.Say("there"). Then you can extend the class and add methods.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, however, `Hello` is **both** an extensible class and a function. It's an odd combination but I'm hoping there's a way to express this with TypeScript since it is definitely possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to do it is to declare `Hello` as a variable having a type which is an interface with both callable and constructor signatures:

```
// this is the type for an object that new Hello() creates
declare interface Hello  { 
    foo(a: string): void;
}

// this is the type for Hello variable
declare interface HelloType {
    (text: string): void;
    new (...args: any[]): Hello;
}

declare var Hello: HelloType;

// can be used as a class
class Hi extends Hello { 
    bar(b: string): void {
        this.foo(b);
    }
}

// and as a function
Hello('there');
```